# Convert Objective C RXPromise result to Swift 3

Tags: objective-c, swift3, promise

Here is the Objective C routine. The question is how do I handle the result in Swift? The signature says it returns a promise. But I need the thread that is returned.

```
-(RXPromise *) createPublicThreadWithName:(NSString *)name {
```

...

```
// Create the CC object
CCThreadWrapper * thread = [CCThreadWrapper threadWithModel:threadModel];

return [thread push].thenOnMain(^id(id success) {

    RXPromise * promise = [RXPromise new];

    // Add the thread to the list of public threads
    FIRDatabaseReference * publicThreadsRef = [[FIRDatabaseReference publicThreadsRef] child:thread.entityID];
    [publicThreadsRef setValue:@{bNullString: @""} withCompletionBlock:^(NSError * error, FIRDatabaseReference * ref) {
        if (!error) {
            [promise resolveWithResult:thread.model];
        }
        else {
            [[BStorageManager sharedManager].a undo];
            [promise rejectWithReason:error];
        }
    }];

    return promise;

},^id(NSError * error) {
    [[BStorageManager sharedManager].a undo];
    return error;
});
```

It returns a promise but I need the thread. What is the syntax in Swift to gain the thread?

UPDATE: ANSWER::

```
    let block = BNetworkManager.shared().a.publicThread().createPublicThread(withName: name, entityID: name, isHidden: true).thenOnMain

    _ = block!({(result: Any?) -> Any? in
        if let thread = result as! PThread? {
            let chatViewController: UIViewController? = BInterfaceManager.shared().a.chatViewController(with: thread )
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(chatViewController!, animated: true)
        }
        MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)

        return result
    }, {(error: Error?) -> Any? in
        MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)

        return error
    })
```

Comment: Stack overflow isn't a code writing service. What have you tried?

Comment: I get a variant like this with everything I tried:  Cannot convert value of type '(_, _) -> ()' to expected argument type '(promise_completionHandler_t?, promise_errorHandler_t?)' (aka '(Optional<(Optional<Any>) -> Optional<Any>>, Optional<(Optional<Error>) -> Optional<Any>>)')

Answer (score 1):

```
    let block = BNetworkManager.shared().a.publicThread().createPublicThread(withName: name, entityID: name, isHidden: true).thenOnMain

    _ = block!({(result: Any?) -> Any? in
        if let thread = result as! PThread? {
            let chatViewController: UIViewController? = BInterfaceManager.shared().a.chatViewController(with: thread )
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(chatViewController!, animated: true)
        }
        MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)

        return result
    }, {(error: Error?) -> Any? in
        MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)

        return error
    })
```

Comment: How to fetch the result as an Array instead of Any ? 
When I tried giving it as Array, compiler throws error as :

Cannot convert value of type '(Array<_>?) -> Any?' to expected argument type 'promise_completionHandler_t?' (aka 'Optional<(Optional<Any>) -> Optional<Any>>')